# Coordinate differential, differential and basis 1-form - what's the difference?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I'm trying to teach myself a little differential geometry. Sorry if this is a dumb question, but is there a difference between the terms *coordinate differential*, *differential* and *basis 1-form*? I've seen things like $dx,dy,dz$ described as all three. Thanks.

Comment: "Differential" suggests (but is not limited to) differential of a function, i.e., $df$. It could also be a general $1$-form. "Coordinate differential" suggests the differential of a coordinate function. And $dx,dy,dz$ give the standard basis (as a module over smooth functions) of the $1$-forms on $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful.